# Handling unbalanced data in GradientBoostingClassifier using weighted class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, boosting

I have a very unbalanced dataset that I need to build a model on top of that for a classification problem. The dataset has around 30000 samples which around 1000 samples are labelled as—1—, and the rest are 0.  I build the model by the following lines:

```py
X_train=training_set
y_train=target_value
my_classifier=GradientBoostingClassifier(loss='deviance',learning_rate=0.005)
my_model = my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Since, this is an unbalanced data, it is not correct to build the model simply like the above code, so I have tried to use class weights as follows:

```py
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(y_train), y_train)
```

Now, I have no idea how I can use  `class_weights` (which basically includes 0.5 and 9.10 values) to train and build the model using `GradientBoostingClassifier`.

Any idea? How I can handle this unbalanced data with weighted class or other techniques?

Comment: Try the steps mentioned [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

Answer (score 5):

You should be using sample weights instead of class weights. In other words, `GradientBoostingClassifier` lets you assign weights to each observation and not to classes. This is how you can do it, supposing y = 0 corresponds to the weight 0.5 and y = 1 to the weight 9.1:

```
import numpy as np
sample_weights = np.zeros(len(y_train))
sample_weights[y_train == 0] = 0.5
sample_weights[y_train == 1] = 9.1
```

Then pass these weights to the `fit` methodology:

```
my_model = my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight = weights)
```